# Can the "city" be overloaded?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, usage

Can we say so or it doesn't make any sense?

- The city can be ***overloaded*** by cars.

I want to say that there is a pressure on the city because of a great deal of cars.

Is it possible to use "overload" then?

And what's about the usage of "a great deal of" ?

Comment: Funnily enough, to me it sounds perfectly natural and normal.  It's perfectly common to talk about the systems of a city (sewage, political, medical etc).  For me "traffic in 2020 overload the city" is perfectly normal and understandable - it means what it obviously means.

Answer (score 10):

"Overloaded" means you loaded too much into/onto something. You don't really 'load' a city with cars, and this sounds like some individual made a mistake when I think what you are actually trying to say is that the capacity has just been exceeded gradually over time by a constant increase in the number of cars.

I feel it would be more idiomatic to say "the city is **overrun** with cars", which means that it is *filled beyond capacity*.

Here are some other possible alternatives, but do check the definitions as some of them may by a little 'poetical' for use in a purely factual statement:

- inundated
- swamped
- deluged
- overwhelmed

Comment: I just can't agree, the two things are different.  The city could be overrun by (say) a Monghol Horde!    Also, cars .. traffic .. are "always in" a city, if the number of cars is becoming huge, you're not being "overrun".  You could be "overrun" by, say, motorbikes on a weekend motorbike gala where thousands of bikers arrive.  But a city can't be "overrun" by people, "overrun" by cars" or "overrun" by houses - those things "are" the city.  In contrast it's perfectly normal to say "the city's health system is overrloaded" or ".. electrical grid is overloaded".

Comment: @Fattie I can't disagree more. A city can certainly be overrun with people, cars, etc. For example if a demonstration or other large event were taking place downtown, that usage is commonplace.

Comment: This is better than "overloaded", but it does sound a bit weird, since it seems like the people are taking over!

Comment: @Fattie you'll notice that my answer states "overrun **with** cars", not 'by', which would indicate intent. You're quite wrong in your assertions and you should perhaps use a tool like ngrams to put them to the test.

Comment: To me "overrun" has a more than usual negative connotation, like you'd use it to describe  there being too many rats or pigeons in the city, but not cars, or even people unless you were viewing those people as undesirable invaders or something.  If it's just the normal occupants of the city, it would be quite insulting to refer to the city as "overrun" with them.

Comment: @DarrelHoffman I think that 'overrun with cars' is meant to be negative. People do own too many cars and there are very few people who can argue with that, even the ones that own lots of cars. As for people - you could certainly use it in a negative sense, if you suggested that certain *types* of people were overrunning a city. But in most cases it would just mean the same as "crowded".

Answer (score 6):

Even though the meaning is clear, I agree with other answerers that this might not be the best term to use in reference to a city.

If you are intent on using that term, I would suggest being more specific with the object that is being overloaded.  In this case, the city's **road infrastructure** or its **transportation network** would be overloaded.

Answer (score 5):

You will want to consider your prepositions in this case.

- If I say something is *overloaded by* I am making a reference to whoever or whatever did the loading.  For example, *The train's boxcar was overloaded by the railyard workers who had loaded it.*  This means the railyard workers had loaded too much onto the boxcar.
- If I say something is *overloaded with* I am making a reference to the items that have been loaded.  For example, *The train's boxcar was overloaded with wheat.*  This means too much wheat has been added to the boxcar.

In your example you are talking about a city.  The parameters for a city becoming *overloaded* are not clearly defined and as Billy Kerr says, it doesn't quite work in your example.  That being said, your example would be better understood if you said, *The city was overloaded with...*

Comment: the use of "overloaded" to mean "too much weight, in for example a truck" is incredibly obscure and technical.  the overwhelmingly normal use of "overloaded" today is about systems: the computer is overloaded, the IRS is overloaded, the electrical system is overloaded, hospitals are overloaded due to Covid.

Comment: @Fattie I assume you have proof of how overloaded is used these days?  Or is this just a broad assumption we all should share?  Shipping containers from China to rest of the world are never overloaded?  Or people just don't talk about it when it happens?

Comment: I'm sorry, no, I don't have time to do a google search (I'm overloaded with work!) about something so obvious and commonplace - so no, sorry.

Comment: @Fattie the examples you're citing are certainly normal uses of the word, but in no way is it "incredibly obscure" to say that a truck/container/cart is overloaded. In fact, Meriam Webster lists your meaning as [its third definition](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/overload)

Comment: @Fattie It's not an obscure usage, just a usage that the average person is unlikely to be in a position to encounter.

Comment: @Fattie nobody said 'too much weight'.  The response points to too much of the thing being loaded ("wheat", or implicitly the load itself on the boxcar).  This physical sense of overloading can be too many, too long or too wide as well as too heavy.  EllieK's response is essentially "overloaded = too much load"   It's worth pointing out that this is the exact same sense used in your flippant *overloaded with work* example, and also the exact same conceptual sense as in your 'systems' examples.

Comment: You've used blockquote markup. What are you quoting?

Comment: If you said a bridge was overloaded with cars then people would surely be expecting the rest of the story to involve more excitement than a long commute (perhaps some kind of emergency rescue situation).

Comment: It's also common to treat devices as actors, and use them in phrases that seem to anthropomorphize them. E.g. "He was run over by a car."

Comment: “If I say something is _overloaded by_ I am making a reference to whoever or whatever did the loading,” is simply untrue in at least my dialect of English (Northeast US)—the preposition _by_ can equally refer to the people who did it **or** the things it was done with. As such, _overloaded by boxes_ and _overloaded by the movers_ are both equally valid and reasonable constructions. Insisting that _with_ “must” be used here is incorrect. In fact, _by_ would be my first choice most of the time (though of course I am not saying _with_ is wrong either).

Comment: @KRyan *The storage shed was overloaded by boxes.*  I would understand that.  *The storage shed was overloaded from boxes.*  That too.  *The storage shed was overloaded with boxes.*  One of those sounds best. I was just trying to provide the one sounded best while demonstrating how the prepositions work in that situation.

Comment: @EllieK I mean, OK, but saying that *by* means this one thing, when in fact it can mean more than that one thing—including the thing asked about in the question—depending on context, is misleading. I find the suggestion in the question a perfectly natural choice.

Comment: @KRyan I checked the definition of **by**. I don't find one that functions as a substitute for with.  Could you point me to that definition?

Comment: @EllieK All I have is decades of experience as a native English speaker interacting almost exclusively with native English speakers; if dictionaries have failed to capture that usage of the word by a substantial population of those using the language, that’s on them.

Comment: @KRyan This is a learners' site.  Your experience with the language is no doubt a valid asset when assisting posters but your hubris is not helpful.  If my answer included *was overloaded from* you would have been correct to call it out as an incorrect usage.  When paired with your usage of *overloaded by*, however, it sounded pretty good to your ear.  **By** means many things.  I do not claim it means one thing.

Comment: I agree that "by" seems okay

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't sound very natural to me, although it is understandable.

We often use "too many" to express something like this.  It means "an excess of".

Examples:

The city has too many cars.

There are too many people in the room.

There are too many customers in the shop.

Answer (score -2):

### Quite simply, yes

This is a perfectly normal, natural thing to say, at least where I am from, which is New York City. The City is *often* “overloaded by cars,” and that’s not at all an unusal observation to make, or way to phrase it.

It’s not the same as being *overrun* by cars—the cars aren’t every where *per se* (New York City has the lowest per-household rates of car ownership in the USA by a huge margin), or “taking over” (again, most people don’t use them) but they are in excess of the city’s capacity to handle cars (even a small fraction of NYC’s population is still a huge number of people), resulting in heavy traffic and impossible parking (my wife spent two hours looking for a spot just yesterday! my turn for that tomorrow).

Instead, the emphasis here is on *capacity*—the City only has so many parking spots, only so much room for traffic to move smoothly, and so on—and that is being overwhelmed. Stuff that is held against your capacity is the *load* on that capacity—in any kind of metric, not just weight—and in this case, we have *overload*. So yes, I think this is a rather ideal verb to use.

And *by* is a perfectly reasonable preposition to use—*with* would be equally fine—since the things taking up capacity are the cars. The preposition *by* could also refer to the people who did the loading—in this case, I guess, the drivers?—but context here would be quite clear that the cars didn’t do the loading, they are the things that have been loaded. *By* could work either way.

So yes, “the city can be overloaded by cars,” that’s perfectly fine.